# Does scaffolding mean creating a table in the database as well?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I know that scaffolding means adding the CRUD operations in the controller for the model. When a model is created and when we add a scaffold controller method it creates the table in the database and then creates the Action method. I suppose this is what happens during scaffolding. Corrections on my understanding are really appreciated.

So now the question is when I add a new model to an existing project and add a scaffold controller shouldn't the above be happening? Create the table in the database and add the controller? Or does it require any additional steps to achieve the same? Or is it that my above understanding about scaffolding applies only for a new project.

Currently in my existing project when I add a new model a table corresponding to the model is not being created though the controller has been created. I have had this issue before but then I manually added the table to the database (this requires the program to be running for me to access the database; which i do not know why) and once I have also tried Migrations(Don't really remember if it worked; but i think it worked once but never after).

I am dealing with the Code First approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when we use scaffolding, it's not about creating the tables in database.

Scaffolding is just a template provided by Microsoft, for faster development.
When you create a action method in controller whose return type is ActionResult, you can pass model to that View and when actually adding the view to that Action Method, you have to specify the Model which you have created and update from Database.

Please check whether you're going with Database first approach or Code first approach.

Comment: I am using code first approach. But when the model is created for the first time and scaffolding is applied, the tables in the database are also created. If not then, when is the tables  being created? When i started the project i never did anything in my database.

Comment: When using code first approach, tables are created/modified when you do migrations. But for this, you have to add your model (newly created) in the OnModelCreating() method of your Application's DBContext as modelBuilder.Entity<YourNewModel>();

Comment: @CoffeeSipper: Does it apply when i do automatic migrations as well?

Comment: @ViniVasundharan Yes it does. In case of automatic migration, EF will implicitly do the migrations everytime you make a change in your model. It is the easiest and hassle-free form of migration.

Comment: Yes. I always do automatic mugrations. I really do not know how the other should be done.